# How to change iterations to recursion

Tags: c

I've got a problem. I've tried to write program. This is command:

- The user specifies a whole number n>0.

Program:

- Allocates two arrays of numbers of type int size n+1
- Using only these arrays and a small number of statically allocated variables, the program calculates recursively the n line of the Pascal triangle (all binomial symbols with an upper parameter equal to n)
- Prints out the calculated values
- Memory slowing down

Example

```
input: 5

output: 1 5 10 10 5 1
```

I wrote iteration, but I have no idea how change this for recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int n,i,k;
    int * array_1;
    int * array_2;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n=='0') printf("%d", 1);
    if(n=='1') printf("%d %d", 1, 1);

    array_1 = (int*)calloc(n+1,sizeof(int));
    array_2 = (int*)calloc(n+1,sizeof(int));

    array_1[0] = 1;
    array_1[1] = 1;
    k=1;

    while(k!=n)
    {

        for(i=0; i<=k+1; i++)
        {
        if(i==0)
        {
            array_2[0] = 1;
        }
        else if(i==n)
        {
            array_2[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            array_2[i] = array_1[i] + array_1[i-1];
        }
        }

        for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
        {
            array_1[i] = array_2[i];
            array_2[i] = 0;
        }

        k++;
    }

    for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array_1[i]);
    }

    free(array_1);
    free(array_2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have your recursive function calculate one row of the triangle.  If it's the first row, it just places a single `1` in the array.  For all other rows, it first calls itself to place the previous row in the array, then iterates over that array, summing adjacent pairs to produce the next row in the second array.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive version could look something like the following, with the actual work being left to fill-in under the two `/* ... */` comments. The missing code essentially exists in the iterative version as posted, it just needs to be retrofitted here.

```
void recurse(int k, int n, int *array_1, int *array_2)
{
    /*
        print previously calculated k-th row in array_1
    */

    // nothing left to do
    if (k == n + 1) return;

    /*
        calculate next (k+1)-th row in array_2 
    */

    // swap arrays and repeat
    recurse(k + 1, n, array_2, array_1);
}

int main()
{
    int n, *array_1, *array_2;

    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) return 1; // input error
    if (n < 0) return 1; // invalid input

    array_1 = (int*)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int));
    array_2 = (int*)calloc(n + 1, sizeof(int));

    array_1[0] = 1;
    recurse(1, n, array_1, array_2);

    free(array_1);
    free(array_2);
    return 0; // done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answer :). This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void recurse (int k, int n, int *array_1, int *array_2)
{
    int i;
    if(k==n+1) return;

    for(i=1; i<=k+1; i++) array_2[i] = array_1[i] + array_1[i-1];

    recurse(k+1, n, array_2, array_1);
}

void output(int n, int *array_1, int *array_2)
{
    int i;

    if(n%2!=0)
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) printf("%d ", array_1[i]);
    else
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) printf("%d ", array_2[i]);

}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int * array_1;
    int * array_2;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n=='0')
     {
        printf("%d", 1);

        return 0;
    }
    else if(n=='1')
    {
        printf("%d %d", 1, 1);
        return 0;
    }

    array_1 = (int*)calloc(n+1,sizeof(int));
    array_2 = (int*)calloc(n+1,sizeof(int));

    array_1[0] = array_1[1] = array_2[0] = 1;

    recurse(1, n, array_1, array_2);
    output(n, array_1, array_2);


    free(array_1);
    free(array_2);
    return 0;
}
```